# read message text without getting all the content

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

```
public void getMessageById(
            @PathParam("folderName") String folderName,
            @PathParam("id") String id) {

        MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
        MimeMessage mimeMessage = null;
        try {

            Store store = mailSession.getStore();
            store.connect("localhost", email, password);
            Folder folder = store.getDefaultFolder();
            folder = folder.getFolder(folderName.toUpperCase());
            folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

            SearchTerm searchTerm = new MessageIDTerm(id);
            Message[] messages = folder.search(searchTerm);


            if (messages.length > 0) {
                mimeMessage = (MimeMessage) messages[0];
            }

            if (mimeMessage != null) {

                Object objRef = mimeMessage.getContent();

                if (objRef != null) {

                    // if message content is not multipart
                    if (!(objRef instanceof Multipart)) {

                        //get message text here
                                System.out.println(mimeMessage.getContent().toString())
                    } else {
                        Multipart multipart = (Multipart) objRef;

                        for (int i = 0; i < multipart.getCount(); i++) {
                            BodyPart bodyPart = multipart.getBodyPart(i);
                            if (bodyPart.isMimeType("text/*")) {
                                //get message text here
                                System.out.println(bodyPart.getContent()
                                        .toString())
                            }
                            if (!Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(bodyPart
                                    .getDisposition())) {
                                continue; // dealing with attachments only
                            }

                            if (bodyPart.isMimeType("image/*")) {


                            }



                        }

                    }

                }

            }

            folder.close(false);
            store.close();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

The problem is that it take long time to fetch message text  .

Is        **Object objRef = mimeMessage.getContent();** fetching all the content , if so is there any way  to avoid fetching all the contents

Thanks for help ...

Answer (score 0):

Rather than calling getContent and switching on whether it's a Multipart or not, use mimeMessage.isMimeType("multipart/*") and mimeMessage.isMimeType("text/*").  See the [msgshow.java sample program](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#Samples).

Instead of fetching the text content all at once, you can use bodyPart.getInputStream to read it incrementally, which might help depending on what you're doing with it once you read it.

And of course you can use the Folder.fetch method to prefetch message metadata to speed up other parts of processing the messages.  See the msgshow.java program again for an example.